# BamL в Xaml (исправить) и обратно в BAml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, дизассемблирование

Достал ресурсы программы (редактировать) через ilasm, но вот проблема файлы resources бинарны. Ладно установил telerik diasembler и достал resx и блин опять проблема файл baml
 Нашел в wiki что это бинарник и нужно преобразовывать, а как не знаю подскажите

ПРограмма на C# Net

Как сделать конвертацию или как их редактировать ресурсы

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можете [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) попробовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: название проекта как бы намекает, что так делать не совсем хорошо.

Comment: Будете сообщником если что ;)

Comment: Сообщником что за дело